# Легкий прокси сервер на линукс

Tags: linux, proxy

Есть ли прокси сервер для линукс, который бы запускался из консоли, например так:

```
# light-proxy --port=3128 --log proxy.log
```

И после этой команды он просто слушал все запросы с порта 3128 в файл proxy.log
Если есть, то подскажите как называется.

Comment: А отвечать он что нить должен ?

Comment: в лог файл, всю информацию о запросах (заголовки, тело и тд)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Масса вариантов:

```
apt-cache search http proxy | grep proxy
```

И из них выбираете все, что имеет в названии micro, light, tiny, tidy, small

меня устроил micro-proxy

Comment: Выбрал micro-proxy, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Есть https://mitmproxy.org/, который удобно выводит в консоль все http-сессии с возможностью просмотра запросов и ответов. Для целей отладки или просмотра http-трафика - самое то.